# unexpected behavior when using cin twice

Tags: c++

I have the following c++ code in a console program:

```
float var1, var2;

cin >> var1;
cin >> var2;
```

When I am about to enter the second variable and use the right arrow key, the input of the first variable starts to appear on the screen. If I hit enter, the second variable will take the value that appeared on the screen. Do I need to reset the cin buffer?
I tried to make use of:

```
cin.clear();
```

and:

```
cin.ignore();
```

but the behavior stays.

Comment: What Operating System? (in other words "what char sequence is sent when Right Arrow is pressed").  Also why Right Arrow?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu/bash shell. I think it's OS/command shell specific.

Comment: I am using borland c++ 6.0 and the program runs in a console

Comment: It's when the cursor is waiting for input of the second variable and the right arrow key is used, it then walkes through the cin buffer and displays the value of the first variable. Furthermore, when I use then the left arrow key to go back to the beginning of the input I can start entering a value shifting the value displayed so far to the right, like inserting. So, while using the right arrow key, it fetches the digits from the previous variable that was entered before. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

This hast nothing todo with c++. What you're experiencing is a feature of `cmd.exe` where the use of the *right arrow key* gets your previously typed line (character for character) *if* the right arrow is pressed as first keystroke on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do. Just know compiler behavior. `cin` will take space(s) or next lines (\n) separated value. Now up and down arrow navigate down the history so you get previous input in console. You can test from command prompt.

Comment: You are right, so it is a feature so to say, good to know, because it may be useful too...